# How do we attach multiple images on intent in android email

Tags: java, android, email, email-attachments

I'm struggling with attaching more than one image before before sending it to gmail or other email client. I would like to have each button attach an image, for example I would like user to attach on first button, copy of ID then another button, proof of payment copy(image).

My java code

```
 private void openFolder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}

private void openFolder2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     {
         URI = data.getData();
         tvAttachment.setText(URI.getLastPathSegment());
         tvAttachment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

         URI2 = data.getData();
         tvAttachment2.setText(URI.getLastPathSegment());
         tvAttachment2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
}

private void sendEmail() {
    try {
        String recipient = "kondja99@gmail.com";
        subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
        message = "Full Name: " + Name.getText().toString() + "\n" + "Cellphone No: " + Number.getText().toString();
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        if (URI != null) {
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
        }
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed, retry! " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` rather than `ACTION_SEND`. Also note that `plain/text` is not a valid MIME type and is not the MIME type of your image.

Comment: I've tried to use ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE, I don't understand what is meant by valid MIME type for my image.

Comment: The MIME type that you put on the `Intent` for `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` is supposed to be the MIME type for the content in `EXTRA_STREAM`, if you are using `EXTRA_STREAM` (which you are). So, you should be using a MIME type associated with your image. Also, FWIW, `plain/text` is not a valid MIME type in any case -- plain text is `text/plain`.

Comment: I've tried yet I'm still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `sendEmail` function to the following:

```
private void sendEmail() {
    try {
        String recipient = "kondja99@gmail.com";
        subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
        message = "Full Name: " + Name.getText().toString() + "\n" + "Cellphone No: " + Number.getText().toString();
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("*/*");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        uris.add(URI);
        uris.add(URI2);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed, retry! " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

As someone in comments pointed out, your MIME type is invalid (reversed.) Safest bet is to use `"*/*"`. You also need to use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` for the Intent action since you are attaching multiple Uris.

Comment: In the camera/photos app you might have to long click to select more than one image. It varies by device/manufacturer.